# Supend/Resume Thread, Specificly execution on code by the procressor Linux

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, cpu-usage, pbs

I'm working on a program that may be run under PBS with a specific CPU count, less than the total number of CPU's. I have previously that PBS enforces this limited by terminating the program if it exceeds the limit.

My program will use threads, however they will have several blocking commands, and I want to run other threads during this time, hence I would have the thread be suspended and placed in a queue while another thread would be resumed.

However Linux doesn't implement pthread_suspend and such. And the work around is to use mutexs however this works at low level by a loop that repeatably checks the state and locks it possible, I.e. it use cpu cycle even though the thread isn't running, hence it I use this method even though only N threads are running >N cpus may be being used and PBS would terminate the program.

Dose any one have a workaround that wouldn't cause this problem?

Ultimately my goal is to prevent my program from using more than N processor with out wasting processor time during blocking calls and solution to this (for Linux and Windows) I would be happy with.

Comment: That isn't how a mutex works.

Comment: I'm not convinced you aren't over thinking this but if this does remain a legit concern you can look into pinning your threads to a limited set of CPUs with `sched_setaffinity` and `pthread_setaffinity_np`.

Comment: @Duck do you know of a similar method for windows platforms?

Comment: I am by no stretch a Windows guy but I think it is SetThreadAffinityMask and SetProcessAffinityMask.  Or something close to that.